# Apache Ignite Data Streamer performance issues

Tags: c#, ignite

Ignite cluster is running in the AWS k8s. A .NET thin client windows service is adding data to this Ignite cluster with port forwarding enabled in the client machine.

Thin client is using Data Streamer to add 10,000 records to the Ignite cluster in a batch, total number of records are 1,00,00,000. Each record size is around 1kb.

It took 4 hours to complete writing 1,00,00,000 records to Ignite cluster.

We observed the below issues in the testing.

1). At times each batch (10K records) Data Streamer add operation took more time 2 minutes. Initially it was 10 - 25 seconds.

2). Added tuning parameters did not improve the performance.

3). At time it got struck at Data Streamer add operation for hours. Thin client application had to be killed on this scenario.

Can we get suggestions to improve the Data Streamer add performance and method/timeout to break the add operation when it gets struck?

Spec:

```
replicas: 3
cpu: "3"
memory: "4Gi"
JVM_OPTS: "-DIGNITE_WAL_MMAP=false -Xms512m -Xmx2g -DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Config:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="dataStreamerThreadPoolSize" value="8"/>
    <property name="workDirectory" value="/ignite/work"/>
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="storagePath" value="/ignite/storage"/>
            <property name="walPath" value="/ignite/wal"/>
            <property name="walArchivePath" value="/ignite/walarchive"/>
            <property name="pageSize" value="#{8 * 1024}"/>
            <property name="walCompactionEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationEnabled" value="true"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: How much memory do you have on the servers? 1,00,00,000 x 1KB ~ 10 GB of data. Default maxSize of a data region = 20% of available RAM. Do you observe write throttling? https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/persistence-tuning#pages-writes-throttling.  I suspect a disks-related bottleneck.

Comment: Ignite cluster node is configured with 4GB of RAM. It is pointing 1TB storage space which has 3 IOPS per GB. So we can rule out the disk constraint.

Did not overwrite the default data region size. Set the checkpoint buffer size to 1GB and tried, it did not help. Do we need to increase this further?

Comment: @Prem I'd suggest tweaking client-side options in `DataStreamerClientOptions`: set `PerNodeParallelOperations = 1`, `PerNodeBufferSize = 128` or less. See if this helps.

Comment: How fast is the connection from the client to the server? Can you please measure speed and ping?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Pavel Tupitsyn. I shall try and share the details here.

Comment: Incorporated your suggestions and performed tests for past few weeks. Around 15,00,00,000 records were added to ignite cluster in batches with these changes. During this test the ignite add operation got struck only once after adding almost 12,00,00,000 records in ignite cluster. It resumed the add operation only after terminating and restarting the client application. Made change in the DataStremer Flush as well. Earlier used AutoFlushInterval of 5 seconds. Now removed it and invoked DataStremer Flush method after the Add cycles.  Do you have any further suggestions on this?

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn, One more observation during these tests. Data Streamer Add operation became very slow after adding about 6,00,00,000 records in ignite cluster. In earlier tests I observed that 1,00,00,000 records were added in ~3 hours. With the current tests, approximately 10,00,000 were added in 1 hour. It is a drastic change in the Data Streamer add performance. We configured the Data Streamer Thread Pool size as 8. Can you share your suggestions to improve this?

Comment: @Prem can you please answer the question above? I understand that the server is on a cloud instance, but where is the client? What is the network latency and throughput between the client and the server? What if you run the same test locally - is it faster or not?

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn, we modified the client application as rest api and deployed it in the AWS k8s itself where Ignite cluster is running. Pushed data from the windows machine to this rest api in the similar way and still we could see the delay in DataStreamer add function. It took around 9 seconds to add 5000 records to ignite cluster. Ignite had around 9,00,00,000 records already. Set AutoFlushInterval to zero and invoked Flush after the Add loop. AllowOverwrite is enabled and PerNodeBufferSize is 128. Can we increase the PerNodeBufferSize to large to have better performance?

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn, our IT team checked the network latency earlier and did not find any delay.