# Timeout parameter for DataStreamer in Ignite C# thin client

Tags: c#, ignite

Setup: Ignite cluster is running in aws k8s. Adding data to the ignite cluster using a C# thin client application with port forwarding to the ignite service is enabled in the windows machine.

Using IDataStreamerClient interface to add data to the ignite cluster. Adding data in batches and 10K data for each batch.

Noticed that this add operation gets struck over a period after processing many batches. It is in the frozen state for hours. We could not find any errors in the server and client logs during this time.

We do not find the option of time out for Data Streamer in C#. Can someone help to overcome this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Ignite Data Streamer performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73080585/apache-ignite-data-streamer-performance-issues)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Pavel Tupitsyn. That did not help. I have updated the ticket. Do you have any other suggestion to find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: this question looks like a duplicate of the previous, so let's close it if you agree.

Comment: I agree. Can you share your suggestions in the other ticket?